# Using ggplot2 in R and a legend will not show up in my figure. Why is that?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, linegraph

```
View(PV)                                                                

library(ggplot2)

ssplot <- ggplot(PV, aes(x=year)) + geom_line(aes(y = infinite_horizon), color = "darkred", size = 1) + geom_line(aes(y = through_year_75), color="steelblue", size = 1)

print(ssplot + labs(y="Present Value ($, trillions)", x = "Year") + ggtitle("Measures of Unfunded Social Security Obligations, 2003-2020"))
```

Unfortunately, I can't post images yet, but I'm getting a figure with two lines and no legend.  Why is this the case?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the color in the `aes()` and use `scale_color_manual()` to set the color manually

```r
ggplot(PV, aes(x = year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = infinite_horizon, color = "darkred"), size = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = through_year_75, color="steelblue"), size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("steelblue" = "steelblue", "darkred" = "darkred"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know without seeing an example of your data, but restructuring your code like below will help to troubleshoot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ssplot <- ggplot(PV, aes(x=year)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = infinite_horizon), color = "darkred", size = 1) +
geom_line(aes(y = through_year_75), color="steelblue", size = 1) +
labs(y="Present Value ($, trillions)", x = "Year") +
ggtitle("Measures of Unfunded Social Security Obligations, 2003-2020")

ssplot
```